# How to get information from meta box in WordPress and show it in a page template

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I am having issues to echo metadata of the meta-box on the template page. The data seems to be saved, where am I doing wrong in echoing the data on the page?

The 'hello' that I have put inside the check if the varibale is set is acctualy showing on the page but not the variables themself. I have tried different places for the saving in the information in the functions.php but the place I put it know seems to be the only place that info is saved into them. Is there something wrong there? or how I'm trying to echo them on the page?

This is from my template side, HTML code. (page-facility.php)

```
<aside class="facility-content-sidebar">
  <?php
      if ( isset( $mf ) && '' !== $mf ) {
        echo 'hello';
        echo esc_attr( $mf );
     }
     if ( isset( $ls ) && '' !== $ls ) {
        echo 'hello';
        echo esc_attr( $ls );
     }
  ?>
</aside>
```

This is my whole code for this in functions.php

```
/* Opening Hours meta box on template */
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_openinghours_meta');
function add_openinghours_meta() {
    global $post;

    if(!empty($post))
    {
        $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);

        if($pageTemplate == 'page-facility.php' )
        {
            add_meta_box(
                'openinghours_meta', // $id
                'Öppettider', // $title
                'display_opening_information', // $callback
                'page', // $page
                'normal', // $context
                'high'); // $priority
        }
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'display_opening_information' ) ) {

    /**
     * Meta box render function
     *
     * @param  object $post Post object.
     * @since  1.0.0
     */

    function display_opening_information($post) {
        // Add the HTML for the post meta
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
        $openinghours_mf_input_field = ( isset( $meta['openinghours_mf_input_field'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['openinghours_mf_input_field'][0] ) ? $meta['openinghours_mf_input_field'][0] : '';
        $openinghours_ls_input_field = ( isset( $meta['openinghours_ls_input_field'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['openinghours_ls_input_field'][0] ) ? $meta['openinghours_ls_input_field'][0] : '';
        wp_nonce_field( 'openinghours_control_meta_box', 'openinghours_control_meta_box_nonce' ); // Always add nonce to your meta boxes!
        ?>
        <div class="post_meta_extras">
            <p>
                <label><?php esc_attr_e( 'Måndag-Fredag:', 'openinghours_mf_input_field' ); ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="openinghours_mf_input_field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $openinghours_mf_input_field ); ?>">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label><?php esc_attr_e( 'Lördag-Söndag:', 'openinghours_ls_input_field' ); ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="openinghours_ls_input_field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $openinghours_ls_input_field ); ?>">
            </p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'openinghours_save_metabox' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'openinghours_save_metabox' ) ) {
    /**
     * Save controls from the meta boxes
     *
     * @param  int $post_id Current post id.
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    function openinghours_save_metabox( $post_id ) {
        /*
         * We need to verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
         * because save_post can be triggered at other times. Add as many nonces, as you
         * have metaboxes.
         */
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['openinghours_control_meta_box_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['openinghours_control_meta_box_nonce'] ), 'openinghours_control_meta_box' ) ) { // Input var okay.
            return $post_id;
        }

        // Check the user's permissions.
        if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' === $_POST['post_type'] ) { // Input var okay.
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        } else {
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        }

        /*
         * If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted,
         * so we don't want to do anything.
         */
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        /* Ok to save */

        if ( isset( $_POST['openinghours_mf_input_field'] ) ) { // Input var okay.
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'openinghours_mf_input_field', sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['openinghours_mf_input_field'] ) ) ); // Input var okay.
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['openinghours_ls_input_field'] ) ) { // Input var okay.
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'openinghours_ls_input_field', sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['openinghours_ls_input_field'] ) ) ); // Input var okay.
        }

    }

    $mf = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'openinghours_mf_input_field', true );
    $ls = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'openinghours_ls_input_field', true );
}
```

I want the variables to be printed with the info that is put into the meta-box. To show opening hours of the facility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that the `$mf` and `$ls` variables are initialized in the `page-facility.php` template file.

For example:

```html
<aside class="facility-content-sidebar">
  <?php
     //initilize variables
     $mf = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'openinghours_mf_input_field', true );
     $ls = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'openinghours_ls_input_field', true );

     //then check if empty
     if ( isset( $mf ) && '' !== $mf ) {
        echo 'hello';
        echo esc_attr( $mf );
     }
     if ( isset( $ls ) && '' !== $ls ) {
        echo 'hello';
        echo esc_attr( $ls );
     }
  ?>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had put the code;

```
$mf = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'openinghours_mf_input_field', true );
$ls = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'openinghours_ls_input_field', true );
```

inside the function, it was supposed to be within the WordPress loop, I finally figured it out last night, just forgot to post it here. Thank you all for looking at my problem!

So like this instead;

```
<aside class="facility-content-sidebar">
  <?php
      $mf = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'openinghours_mf_input_field', true );
      $ls = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'openinghours_ls_input_field', true );

      if ( isset( $mf ) && '' !== $mf ) {
        echo 'hello';
        echo esc_attr( $mf );
     }
     if ( isset( $ls ) && '' !== $ls ) {
        echo 'hello';
        echo esc_attr( $ls );
     }
  ?>
</aside>
```